# Iptables: Redirect to port 8080 and ACCEPT only one IP address

Tags: linux, firewall, iptables

Background Info: I have rooted an android phone and installed droidwall to get access to iptables.  The kernel version is 2.6.35.7-perf.

Objective: Test the efficiency of a proxy (on port 8080) from a comparison of the traffic flow with and without the proxy.

I am able to get a test without going through the proxy with the rules from [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/218707/iptables-rules-to-allow-http-traffic-to-one-domain-only)

Method: I have creating a test website on a single IP address. I am using an application that monitors how many packets/bytes have been transmitted and recieved by the phone.

Problem: Due to unknown background traffic, unwanted packets are being sent and recieved.

Solution: Use iptables to only allow a connection to one website so I can properly monitor the traffic.

How would I go about this?

Comment: What does this question have to do with Android?

Comment: I'm testing this on an android phone. I guess it is an irrelevant tag tho. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -s 1.2.3.4 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s 1.2.3.4 --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT
```

The first rule should redirect al traffic from 1.2.3.4 to the port 8080, while the second states to accept such packet.

Now you should set on DROP the default policy for INPUT so that every other packet is discarded:

```
iptables -P INPUT DROP
```

Be careful. This is a very restrictive rule.

Comment: I put this in, however I still cannot get access to the website. (It is a test website that I created) When I list the iptables rules,I can see the packets are not getting redirected. These are the only rules I have. What could I be doing wrong here?

Comment: It is almost like my PREROUTING chain isn't working. When I put the same code in the OUTPUT chain, it redirects at least a few packets. Any thoughts?

Comment: You said you're using it on an android phone... actually I have no idea about android iptables support. Moreover, I cannot understand why you need to set iptables rules on an android phone to access a website. Edit your post and be more specific about your environment. We can't help you like this.

Comment: From my understanding, iptables should be the same since it is linux based. I have the phone rooted and droidwall installed. I am able to limit access to a single website with these rules i ran accros: [iptable rules](http://serverfault.com/questions/218707/iptables-rules-to-allow-http-traffic-to-one-domain-only). The only addition is I am trying to run the traffic through a proxy on port 8080.

Comment: Iptables depends on kernel and only God knows which kernel is running in your android version. Again, edit your question: you were speaking about accept traffic from only a website, now you're speaking about limit the access to websites (that is something very different). Tell us exactly what you need and we'll try to help you.

Comment: I have edited the question to be more specific. Sorry for the confusions.

Thanks so much for sticking with me and all your help Zagorax.

Comment: Sorry, but I can test it on my android phone and for my understanding you should be able to connect to a proxy that runs locally on your phone since you have this rule `iptables -I INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT` that allows all packets on the loopback interface.